# Error running Gulp in Sylius

Tags: npm, gulp, sylius

I've got a new install of Sylius that I'm working with. I just installed NPM and Gulp, and wanted to run Gulp for the first time. I'm getting an error, and have never worked with Gulp or Sylius before, so it's a little hard for me to understand:

```
gulp
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-if'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/Gulpfile.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

This is happening on a Ubuntu system, but it also seems to be throwing the same error on my Mac, with a copy of the same Sylius install on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running `npm i -S gulp-if` in your project. What this does is install the `gulp-if` package and saves it in your `package.json` file

Comment: There were a long chain of packages that I had to install in this same manner, so I simply alernated between running gulp, checking the dependency, and installing the dependency. Rinse, later, repeated and eventually everything started working. Thanks!